# 'href=' not working in project

Tags: html, forms, href

**href="link here"** doesn't work for me. i.e clicking the updates button doesn't load its page. Here's that part of the code:

```
<div class="st-container">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked" id="st-control-1"/>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2" />
    <a href="../update/update.html">Updates</a>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-3"/>
    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-4"/>
    <a href="#">Ideals</a>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-5"/>
    <a href="#">Support</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when you click the "Updates" link?

Comment: it stays on the same page.

Comment: By "link", I mean the `<a href>` -- not the `<input>`. Are you expecting that clicking an `<input>` will navigate to a URI? If so, I don't see any code here that would do that.

Comment: ? no code? hmm i thought this would do the trick. do you have a sample or something i can look at?

Comment: If the desired effect is that clicking an `<input>` will navigate to another page, you'll need some javascript. This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789120/how-do-i-create-a-button-href

Comment: No, it doesn't fix it. It just makes it look like it's working. It's not.

Comment: @Rob Care to elaborate?

Comment: so the page loading means that its not fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify: The issue here does not appear to be incorrect paths or the non-existence of files.

The OP wants to use radio buttons for navigation, so that clicking an `<input>` will navigate to a different URI.

This can be done with javascript using an `onclick` handler.
A few variations are detailed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789120/how-do-i-create-a-button-href

```
<input type="button" value="Page" onclick="location.href='http://example.com';">
```

Be advised that usability can be adversely affected by using form elements for navigation. One example: if a user has javascript disabled in his/her browser, the navigation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do that in various ways**

**It depends of what you want, choosing the right code will help you website functionality.**

1.You can have only the "button"(radio) with the link:(there are two
    ways)

*1.1-If the page is on you host:*

> < input type="radio" name="radio-set"id="st-control2"
>   onclick="location.href='../update/update.html'"> Updates <  /input>

*1.2-If the page is on another host:*

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2" onclick="parent.location='../update/update.html'">Updates</input>
```

2.You can have only the label with the link:

> ```
> <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2"/>
> <a href="../update/update.html"><b>Updates</b></a>
> ```

3.And ou can have both link and "button"(radio) with the link:

> ```
> <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2"
> onclick="location.href='../update/update.html'"/> <a
> href="../update/update.html"><b>Updates</b></a>
> ```

4.You can also use a button(Pesonaly i advise it.)

> ```
> <button type="button" id="st-control-2" onclick="location.href='../update/update.html'"><b>Update</b></button>
> ```

**Here's some tags info you can add to:**

[HTML < a > Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

[HTML < input > Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

[HTML < label > Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)